# How do we use a Random Forest for sentence-classification using word-embedding

Tags: python, nlp, random-forest, word-embedding

When we have a random forest, we have n-inputs and m-features e.g for 3 observations and 2 features we have

```py
X = [[1,23],[0,-12],[-0.5,29]]
y = [1,0,1]
```

and we can train a RandomForest with

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForest()
model.fit(X,y)
```

If I have made a word-embedding using, say, a 100-dimensional vector, how do we create the `X` matrice, where each input is a sentence?

Say we have the following 3-dimensional embedding of the words `["I","like","dogs","cats"]`:

```py
I = [-0.5,0,1]
like = [5,2,3]
dogs = [1,2,3]
cats = [3,2,1]
```

then the dataset ["I like dogs","I like cats"] would be

```py
X = [
[[-0.5,0,1], [5,2,3], [1,2,3]],
[[-0.5,0,1], [5,2,3], [3,2,1]]
]
y = ["dog-lover","cat-lover"]
```

which a RF naturally cannot train thus giving the erropr `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.`

Apart from RF might not be suitable for NLP - is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think performing Random Forest classifier on the 3-dimensional input will be possible, but as an alternative way, you can use *sentence embedding* instead of word embedding. Therefore your input data will be 2-dimensional (`(n_samples, n_features)`) as this classifier expected.
There are many ways to get the sentence embedding vector, including *Doc2Vec* and *SentenceBERT*, but the most simple and commonly used method is to make an element-wise average over all the word embedding vectors.
In your provided example, the embedding length was considered as 3. Suppose that the sentence is *"I like dogs"*. So the sentence embedding vector will be computed as follow:

```
I = [-0.5,0,1]
like = [5,2,3]
dogs = [1,2,3]
cats = [3,2,1]

# sentence: 'I like dogs'
sentence = [-0.5+5+1, 0+2+2, 1+3+3] / 3
         = [5.5, 4, 7] / 3
         = [1.8333, 1.3333, 2.3333]
```

Comment: Do you have any references regarding that ? I struggle a bit with the same issue when training a neural network (e.g each feature is 100-dimensional)

Comment: There is some good explanation about the vector averaging method in the third part of [this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/overview/part-3-more-fun-with-word-vectors). [This code](https://www.kaggle.com/arunava21/word2vec-and-random-forest-classification) is also used the same method for the RandomForest classifier. But the neural networks shouldn't have any problem handling word embeddings. For example, you can handle these vectors using the [Embedding Layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/) in Keras library.